# wix toolset radio button condition

Tags: xml, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

How can I modify the provided example, which currently installs both MSI packages, to incorporate a page with radio buttons in the WiX Toolset Bootstrapper within Visual Studio, allowing users to choose which package to install?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="test1" UpgradeCode="bdd11b87-546">
        <!-- <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" /> -->
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" />
            <!--Blank URL-->
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="C:\Users\Package1.msi" />
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="C:\Users\Package2.msi" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```